# Wrap text around shortcode

Tags: plugin-development, shortcode

I use a shortcode handler in my plugin. The shortcode can have different (optional) parameters. And it should be possible to use for example 2 shortcodes on a static WordPress page with text before, between and after the shortcodes.

An example could be:

```
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr

        <table>
        <tr>
        <td>[shortcode option="1"]</td>
        <td>[shortcode option="2"]</td>
        </tr>
        </table>

    invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    Sticky Posts:
    [shortcode option="3"]
m et justo duo dolores et
```

My coding for the shortcode handler is this:

```
function show_posts_handler( $atts, $content=null, $code="" ) {
    //code 4 displaying 
        extract( shortcode_atts( array(
            'sticky' => 'false',
            'latest' => 'false',
            'missions' => 'false',
            'count' => '0',
        ), $atts ) );

        if($sticky != 'false')
        {
            show_sticky_posts();
        } else if($latest != 'false'){
            show_lastest_posts($count);
        }else if($missions != 'false'){
            show_lastest_missions($count);
        }else{
            show_all_posts_from_categories();
        }
}

add_shortcode( 'show_posts', 'show_posts_handler' );
```

The shortcodes should be used in the WYSIWYG editor of pages and not programatically in the template. 
**The problem is "The shortcodes are always displayed before the text".**

Comment: Did you try your example usage? If so, what was wrong with it? What unexpected behavior did you get?

Comment: Nice story, what is the question?

Comment: sorry for the confusion ... I had highlighted my question now. Hope that it is a bit clearer now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without seeing your `show_sticky_posts, show_lastest_posts, show_lastest_missions,show_all_posts_from_categories` i can guess that the shortcode content is always before the post content beacuse this functions are echoing/outputing the result and a shortcode should return content instead so you can try using output buffer  of PHP like this:

```
function show_posts_handler( $atts, $content=null, $code="" ) {
    //code 4 displaying 
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'sticky' => 'false',
        'latest' => 'false',
        'missions' => 'false',
        'count' => '0',
    ), $atts ) );
    ob_start();
    if($sticky != 'false'){
        show_sticky_posts();
    } else if($latest != 'false'){
        show_lastest_posts($count);
    }else if($missions != 'false'){
        show_lastest_missions($count);
    }else{
        show_all_posts_from_categories();
    }
    $output_string = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $output_string;
}

add_shortcode( 'show_posts', 'show_posts_handler' );
```

Comment: the different option write uses for displaying: get_template_part( 'content-list', get_post_format() );